# How can I check for a selectedIndex among dozens of list boxes in order to edit/delete?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have dozens of list boxes on my form.  I want to be able to edit/delete items from those list boxes using only one edit button and only one delete button.  Should a loop be created so I don't have to code an if statement for each list box?  Maybe a custom method? Kind of lost here.

Thanks for the input.

This is the code for one of the list boxes to for edit:

```
 private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Edit an item in the list box
        //If there are no appointments OR no appointment is selected, inform the user and cancel the operation
        if ((!(appointmentList.Count > 0)) || lstDayView.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error! You need to select an appointment!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int index = lstDayView.SelectedIndex;
            var myForm = new Form2(appointmentList[index] as Appointment);
            if (myForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && myForm.Tag is Appointment)
            {
                Appointment appoint = myForm.Tag as Appointment;
                //lstDayView.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                appointmentList.RemoveAt(index);
                appointmentList.Insert(index, appoint);
                //appoint.toListBox(lstDayView, index);
                this.setCal();
            }
        }
```

And this is for delete:

```
 private void btnDeleteApp_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((!(appointmentList.Count > 0)) || lstDayView.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error! You need to make and/or select an appointment!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to delete?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                appointmentList.RemoveAt(lstDayView.SelectedIndex); //Issue this is removed the index number from the list not the appointmentList
                this.setCal();
            }
        }
```

Comment: could you please explain more clearly with some example and if possible share your code.

Comment: I guess what you need is a list of the controls. Then you can iterate over this list to find the active one instead of a big `if(box1) else if (box2)...` type statement. Of course, you could even auto-generate this list from the forms content, but that could be risky in case there are list boxes you don't want to consider.

Comment: ListBoxes aren't mutually exclusive like RadioButtons.  Therefore it will be confusing as there is no way to determine which ListBox is the "current" one since they can all have selections at the same time, and they all look the same.  Technically you could track which ListBox was clicked/changed last in a form level variable and use that in your edit/delete routines.  Some possibilities...make the "current" ListBox display differently somehow.  Make all other ListBoxes unselect the current item when a selection is made in one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Form.Controls collection in a foreach loop to check for and manipulate the listboxes.
Another thing you can do is to assign the same selectedindexchanged event to all the listboxes you want to manipulate. The "sender" parameter holds the object that caused the event to fire. You can cast it to a listbox and manipulate it.

**EDIT**:Your basic problem is that you do not know which listbox was last selected. You need to define a variable that will keep the last listbox entered by the user(using the Enter event) and use that variable to delete the item from the listbox.
Example:

```
ListBox lastEnteredListbox = null;

private void aListboxName_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lastEnteredListbox=(ListBox)sender;
}

private void theButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(lastEnteredListbox == null || lastEnteredListbox.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
          MessageBox.Show("You need to select an Item");
          return;
    }

    lastEnteredListbox.RemoveAt(lastEnteredListbox.SelectedIndex);
}
```

You need to set the Enter event of all listboxes you wish to manipulate to the aListBoxName_Enter method.

In case that you want to simply delete the same index from all listboxes, you just loop through the controls collection of the form and do an `if(control is ListBox) ((ListBox)control).RemoveAt(index);`

Answer (score 0):

As ThunderGr suggests, you can attach the same event handler to all Listboxes so that the same logic can be applied.  When it comes to iterating (both to assign the event handlers initially, and to subsequently work on the collection as a whole), I would set the `Tag` property of each control to something relavent (e.g. "List"), and then you can do:

```
foreach(var control in Controls.Where(c => c.Tag == "List"))
{
    // work with control here (casting to ListBox appropriately).
}
```

You could even make this a method of your form that returns `IEnumerable<ListBox>` like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ListBox> ListBoxes
{
    get
    {
        return Controls.Where(c => c.Tag == "List").Cast<ListBox>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing another  ListItem (`lstDayView`) from `appointmentList` List.

**Replace This :**

```
appointmentList.RemoveAt(lstDayView.SelectedIndex);
```

**With following :**

```
appointmentList.RemoveAt(appointmentList.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks for that catch.  I forgot about that part.  We will fix that and see if it works.